# Magnetic field at the center of a rotating charged square loop

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electricity, magnetic-fields

Consider a square loop of side length $2a$, with a total charge $Q$ uniformly distributed along its sides (so that the line charge density is $\lambda=\frac{Q}{8a}$), set spinning at angular velocity $\omega$. What is the magnetic field for a stationary observer at its centre?

[image: Diagram of a segment of the spinning square loop]

The field obviously points directly perpendicular to the plane of the loop. We just need to determine the magnitude.

For the quasistatic case, a simple application of the Biot-Savart law with $\vec I\ dl\to \vec v\ dq$ on tiny segments of charge $dq=\lambda dl=\frac{Q}{8a}dl$ a distance $r$ from the centre yields

$$dB=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{\lvert \vec v\times\hat r\rvert}{r^2}dq\\=\frac{\mu_0Q}{32\pi a}\frac{r\omega}{r^2}dl\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{32\pi a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{l^2+a^2}}dl$$

since $\vec v\perp\vec r\implies\lvert\vec v\times\hat r\rvert=v=r\omega$ and $r=\sqrt{l^2+a^2}$. So

$$B=8\int_{l=0}^{l=a}dB\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{4\pi a}\int_0^a\frac{dl}{\sqrt{l^2+a^2}}\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{4\pi a}\ln[\sqrt{l^2+a^2}+l]_0^a\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{4\pi a}\ln(\sqrt 2+1)$$

However, how would I compute the exact field? (including the effects of relativity and finite speed of electromagnetic "news")

My attempt involved using the exact magnetic field of a moving point charge (the one derived from the Lienard Wiechert potentials or special relativity) instead of the Biot-Savart law.

$$\vec B=\frac{\mu_0q}{4\pi}\frac{1-v^2/c^2}{(1-\lvert\hat v\times\hat r\rvert^2v^2/c^2)^{3/2}}\frac{\vec v\times\hat r}{r^2}$$

where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the charge and $\vec r$ is the *present* position of the charge. Since $\vec v\perp\vec r$, this simplifies to

$$B=\frac{\mu_0qv}{4\pi r^2\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

Once again, applying this to a tiny segment of the loop in a manner similar to before with the corrected field, we have

$$dB=\frac{\mu_0v}{4\pi r^2\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}dq\\=\frac{\mu_0Qr\omega}{32\pi ar^2\sqrt{1-r^2\omega^2/c^2}}dl\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{32\pi a\sqrt{r^2-a^2}\sqrt{1-r^2\omega^2/c^2}}dr$$

The last step is because $l=\sqrt{r^2-a^2}\implies dl=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-a^2}}dr$. The field at the center will then be

$$B=8\int_{l=0}^{l=a}dB\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{4\pi a}\int_{a}^{\sqrt 2a}\frac{dr}{\sqrt{r^2-a^2}\sqrt{1-r^2\omega^2/c^2}}\\=\frac{\mu_0Q\omega}{4\pi a}\int_{1}^{\sqrt 2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{1-(a\omega/c)^2x^2}}$$

The last step, using the substitution $r=ax$, produces an elliptic integral, which reduces to the correct quasistatic result in the limit $a\omega<<c$. However, my attempt still involved assuming the hoop is still square and uniformly charged. Are these assumptions correct, in the general case? How else could I calculate the correct magnetic field for a stationary observer at the center of the spinning loop?

Comment: What's the axis of rotation ?

Comment: It is perpendicular to the plane of the loop and passes through the loop center